# How to fire JQuery change event when input value changed programmatically?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, onchange

I want to fire the JQuery `change` event when the input text is changed programmatically, for example like this:

```js
$("input").change(function(){
    console.log("Input text changed!");
});
$("input").val("A");
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type='text' />
```

But it doesn't work. How can I make this work?

Answer (score 62, accepted):

> change event only fires when the user types into the input and then loses focus.

You need to trigger the event manually using **[`change()`](https://api.jquery.com/change/)** or **[`trigger('change')`](https://api.jquery.com/trigger/)**

```js
$("input").change(function() {
  console.log("Input text changed!");
});
$("input").val("A").change();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type='text' />
```

Comment: is this a requirement to call .change() after you've changed .val() of input programmatically? I'm finding that when i change .val() programmatically, and set .focus() so I can put cursor at the end of added value text. and then click outside of input. it clears the input...

Comment: @AkinHwan : `change()` method is calling for triggering the method programatically since `val()` method doesn't trigger the change event

Answer (score 8):

The event handler `.change()` behaves like a form submission - basically when the value changes on submit the console will log. In order to behave on text input you would want to use input, like below:

```js
$("input").on('input', function(){
    console.log("Input text changed!");
});
$("input").val("A");
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type='text' />
```

Answer (score 4):

What you need to do is trigger the `change` event after you've set the text. So you may create a function to do that so you won't have to repeat it every time you need to update the text, like this:

```
function changeTextProgrammatically(value) {
    $("input").val( value );
    $("input").trigger( 'change' ); // Triggers the change event
}

changeTextProgrammatically( "A" );
```

I've updated the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/pedromendessk/cyqqkjnb/2/),

Answer (score 1):

You can use the DOMSubtreeModified event:

```
$('input').bind('DOMSubtreeModified',function(){...})
```

If you want to fire **both** user and code changes:

```
$('input').bind('input DOMSubtreeModified',function(){...})
```

This event is marked as deprecated and sometimes quite CPU time consuming, but it may be also very efficient when used carefully...

Answer (score 0):

jquery change event only works when the user types into the input and then loses focus. So you can use the following workaround to do so:-
Let's say you have a button clicking on which results in change in value of input. (this could be anything else as well instead of a button)

```
var original_value = $('input').val();
$('button').click(function(){
var new_value = $('input').val();
if(original_value != new_value ){
   //do something
  }
//now set the original value to changed value (in case this is going to change again programatically)
original_value = new_value;
})
```